# How to perform a full text search in MongoDb with C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using the latest MongoDb Api.

I have some entity

```
class Entity
{
    ObjectId Id {get;set;}
    string Text {get;set;}
}

 //Create text index   
 EntityCollection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(IndexKeys<Entity>.TextAll().ToBsonDocument());
```

I can see this index presents in DB, but when I'm trying to perform search in MongoVUE with a query

```
{ $text: {$search: '<existent-word>'}}
```

so i receive nothing.

Maybe I need to rebuild the index in some way? How to do that from C#?

How to perform Full Text Search functionality with a sorting by relevance (score) in C#?

Update. Ind

```
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "Db.entities"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_fts" : "text",
                        "_ftsx" : 1
                },
                "name" : "$**_text",
                "ns" : "Db.entities",
                "weights" : {
                        "$**" : 1
                },
                "default_language" : "english",
                "language_override" : "language",
                "textIndexVersion" : 2
        }
]
```

Comment: Please show us the output of `getIndices()`.

Comment: Can't find a such method in C# api

Comment: in the mongo shell, issue `use yourDatabaseName`, then `db.yourCollectionName.getIndices()`.

Comment: it shows '[]' - no indices. But in MongoVUE I can see index $**_text

Comment: Have you put in your database and collection names? An *existing* collection has at least one index - the one for `_id`.